# multiple marker with one cluster manager

Tags: flutter, maps, cluster-computing

I'm using  flutter cluster manager on map. I have 10 locations in Greece, 20 in Romania and 10 in Turkey. When I zoom out a lot they are merged and I see 40 in bulgaria. Can I have them separated in countries no matter the zoom?